# TextBox with Numeric Input

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I am working on a database application and using this class to validate numeric numbers on KeyPress event of TextBox.

The numbers may have (-) negative values with fixed decimal places (third parameter dPlaces) e.g. 10000, -1000, 12345.45, -12345.45

After adding a decimal, I am not able to edit other digits although without a decimal it is working perfectly.

Thanks in advance

```
    public static class Util    
    {
    public static void NumInput(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e, int dPlaces)
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != '.' && (e.KeyChar != '-'))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        // only allow one decimal point
        if (e.KeyChar == '.' && (sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        var a = (sender as TextBox).SelectionLength;

        // only allow minus sign at the beginning
        var x = (sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('-');
        if (e.KeyChar == '-' && (sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('-') > 0)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
        {

            TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;

            if (textBox.Text.IndexOf('.') > -1 &&
                     textBox.Text.Substring(textBox.Text.IndexOf('.')).Length >= dPlaces + 1)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And using [NumericUpDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown(v=vs.110).aspx) instead? (I.E. Don't reinvent the wheel)

Comment: Also take into account that users could paste data into your TextBox - they won't necessarily have to type.

Comment: NumericUpDown can not be used with Decimal values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because of Logical operation in your IF BLOCK for comparing length  =3 and char  = '.'.

Change that last part of your code with : (**EDIT** : To handle the issue of inserting text before '.')

```
       if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
        {



            TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
            // get position of new char to be inserted
            int position = textBox.SelectionStart;

            if (textBox.Text.IndexOf('.') > -1 && position > textBox.Text.IndexOf('.')) // check location of new char

                if(!(textBox.Text.Substring(textBox.Text.IndexOf('.')).Length <= dPlaces + 1))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }

        }
```

This will do your job..!!!

**EDIT :** Also Do the following to STOP Copy/Past in textbox

```
        textbox.ShortcutsEnabled = false;
```

Comment: If I enter 1234.56 and then try to insert a number between 2 and 3 (to make it 12034.56), it doesnt work.